# SpriteKit shader uniform update interval

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit, shader, glsles

I'm using uniforms to make smooth inshader animation. Because I can not obtain or change `u_time` I've use custom timestamp, animation start and animation duration uniforms, but, unfortunately, updating uniform values in `update` func didn't cause immediately uniform update(looks like it's updated only once per ~0.5 seconds, even when update called every 1/60 second).
May be someone know how to get/update `u_time` uniform or update custom uniforms smoothly?

Comment: Sounds weird to me, are you sure your timestamps resolution is sufficient?